# If the median of a random variable is below its expectation, is this still true for a repeated sampling of this random variable?

Tags: probability-theory, independence, means, median

Let $X$ be a real-valued random variable satisfying

1. $\mathsf E X = 0$ and
2. $\mathsf P(X\le 0)\ge\frac12$.

In other words, $X$ is a (centralised) random variable whose median is below its mean. For instance, the distribution of wealth is (up to a constant) such a distribution: The median of income/net worth/etc. is always below the mean, since the mean is dragged up by a small number of very wealthy/high-income/etc. individuals.

---

**My question.** Suppose that $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ for some $n\in\mathbb N$ are all independent and identically distributed like $X$. Let $S_n\overset{\text{Def.}}=X_1+\dots+X_n$. Is it true that

$$\mathsf P(S_n \le 0)\ge \frac12$$ ? In other words, if we take an "unbiased sample" of $X$ with size $n$, is the median of that sample still below its mean? (Or again in other words: If we take a bunch of "unbiased samples" of $X$ of size $n$, would the average "observation" be higher than the median "observation" ?)

---

**Remark 1.** By inductive reasoning, it would be enough to prove that if $Y$ is indepedent of $X$ and identically distributed like $X$, then

$$\mathsf P(X+Y\le 0)\ge \frac12.$$

**Remark 2.** There is a very easy lower bound:

$$\mathsf P(X+Y\le 0)\ge\mathsf P(X\le 0\cap Y\le 0)=\mathsf P(X\le0)\mathsf P(Y\le 0)\ge\frac14,$$

however, I want to achieve $\frac12$, not $\frac14$.

**Remark 3.** If $X$ doesn't satisfy $\mathsf EX=0$, then the answer is "no". For instance, if $\mathsf P(X=-1)=\mathsf P(X=2)=\frac12$, then

$$\mathsf P(X\le0)=\frac12,$$

but

$$\mathsf P(X+Y\le 0)=\frac14.$$

Comment: Follow-up: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4136634/631742

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this modification of the example in Remark 3?

If $\mathsf P(X=-1)=\frac23$, $\mathsf P(X=2)=\frac13$, then

$$\mathsf P(X\le0)=\frac23,$$

but

$$\mathsf P(X+Y\le 0)=\frac49.$$

Comment: I'm surprised that I missed this and this is very annoying . But thank you!

Comment: Follow-up: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4136634/631742