# Under what conditions does the median of an $n$-sample of a random variable remain below its expectation

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, independence, means, median

Let $X$ be a real-valued random variable satisfying

1. $\mathsf E X = 0$ and
2. $\mathsf P(X\le 0)\ge\frac12$.

In other words, $X$ is a (centralised) random variable whose median is below its mean. For instance, the distribution of wealth is (up to a constant) such a distribution: The median of income/net worth/etc. is always below the mean, since the mean is dragged up by a small number of very wealthy/high-income/etc. individuals.

Suppose that $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ for some $n\in\mathbb N$ are all independent and identically distributed like $X$. Let $S_n\overset{\text{Def.}}=X_1+\dots+X_n$.

---

**My reference request.** Are there any known "nice" conditions on $X$ that are sufficient, so that

$$\mathsf P(S_n\le 0)\ge\frac12$$

holds? As was shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4136624/631742) by [hgmath](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/886804/), in general, the above inequality doesn't hold even if $n=2$.